# Is it safe to delete the original admin user after creating a new one?

Tags: permission, user-account, administrator

I have a MBP running Mojave that I got from a colleague. It's got a single user account, let's say "John", and that user is an administrator account. I don't want John's account, I want my own. And John will not need that account anymore.

If I create a new user, "Chris", can I safely delete the old user, `/Users/john` folder and everything else?

My instinct is that it should be completely fine, but I want to make sure there isn't anything super-special about the auto-created administrator account in macOS that I would be losing by deleting that original account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it’s safe - you only need one admin account. You can delete all the others, just not the last one.

Choose to keep the data or delete the data, but the accounts can all go when you don’t need them.

Comment: Awesome. I'm backing-up the data from the old user, anyway. Worst case: a complete wipe with a new original-admin-user, but this will be a whole lot faster than that.

Comment: Always forward @ChristopherSchultz - that’s a good plan...